# how can we use translate fucntion of fairseq without bpe

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch, nlp, machine-translation

i was using pretrained model of japanes translation , trained via fairseq http://www.kecl.ntt.co.jp/icl/lirg/jparacrawl/

this contains following files

model.pt dict.en.txt dict.ja.txt spm.en.nopretok.model spm.en.nopretok.vocab spm.ja.nopretok.model spm.ja.nopretok.vocab

i wanted to use

```
  from fairseq.models.transformer import TransformerModel
    zh2en = TransformerModel.from_pretrained(
      '/path/to/checkpoints',
      checkpoint_file='checkpoint_best.pt',
      data_name_or_path='data-bin/wmt17_zh_en_full',
      bpe='subword_nmt',
      bpe_codes='data-bin/wmt17_zh_en_full/zh.code'
    )
```

this function of fairseq but i do not have BPE codes file.

please suggest how can i use this pretrined model in python using fairseq

Comment: The `smp` file are from Google's SentencePiece which is an alternative to BPE. You need to segment the input using SentencePiece models first.

Answer (score 0):

i found vocab.model file and it worked using sentencepiece